# Saltstack and Python3 issue

Tags: python, saltstack

I'm having a bit of an issue with the following recipe:

```
setup-compose:
  file.managed:
    - source: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.1/docker-compose-Linux-{{ grains['cpuarch'] }}
    - name: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - source_hash: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.1/docker-compose-Linux-{{ grains['cpuarch'] }}.sha256
    - user: root
    - mode: 744
```

When it runs, I'm getting the following error:

[ERROR   ] Unable to manage file: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 40: invalid start byte

local:

---

```
      ID: setup-compose

Function: file.managed

    Name: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

  Result: False

 Comment: Unable to manage file: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 40: invalid start byte

 Started: 18:10:31.784381

Duration: 1932.928 ms

 Changes:
```

Now I read about all sorts of issues with unicode under Python2, so I'm wondering:

- is there a way to get Saltstack to work with python3? (I'm using an Ubuntu 16 DO droplet, updated to latest kernel but installing Saltstack from official repos also installs Python2 and replacing Python2 by 3 results in

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/bin/salt-call", line 7, in
>
> from salt.scripts import salt_call
>
> ImportError: No module named 'salt'

- barring that, is something that can be done on Python2? I'm a developer but haven't touched Python until very recently so I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of salt and python are you using? [According to the documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/releases/2017.7.0.html#python-3), Salt is working with Python 3.4 or greater starting with salt 2017.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute `apt update` and `apt upgrade` on your minion. The issue indicates that you have outdated packages on the minion, not master.